# Passing XML Data As Parameter In SOAP Request

Tags: xml, api, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have a URL for a WSDL configuration file that I imported into SOAPUI. I filled out the relevant 'form' for the request I want to make named 'SubmitAndRate.' When I send the request, I receive a 200 response. But there is one more field at the bottom called xmlData, which SOAPUI says should be a string, and I believe I'm supposed to place the data from a sample XML request file I was also provided with.

Here is the current request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:SubmitAndRate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:integrationUser>username</tem:integrationUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:integrationPassword>password</tem:integrationPassword>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:userName>usernamea</tem:userName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:originator>ITC</tem:originator>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:companyId>1</tem:companyId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:stateId>11</tem:stateId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:LOBId>1</tem:LOBId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:transactionEffectiveDate>2002-05-30T09:30:10.5</tem:transactionEffectiveDate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:guaranteedRatePeriodEffectiveDate>2002-05-30T09:30:10.5</tem:guaranteedRatePeriodEffectiveDate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:transTypeId>2</tem:transTypeId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:isQuote>true</tem:isQuote>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:persistQuote>true</tem:persistQuote>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:autoCreateAdditionalInterest>false</tem:autoCreateAdditionalInterest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:saveAncillaryChoicePointData>false</tem:saveAncillaryChoicePointData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:xmlData></tem:xmlData>
      </tem:SubmitAndRate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The is the line I believe should contain the XML request data. Says it should be a string in SOAPUI.

```
<tem:xmlData></tem:xmlData>
```

And the XML sample request they provided me looks like:

```
<ACORD>
<SignonRq>
<SignonPswd>
<CustId>
<CustLoginId>username</CustLoginId>
...
```

Since I am coding this in PHP, I need a way to include the XML contents as a string inside of the request. Am I supposed to do something like:

```
<tem:xmlData>
<![CDATA[
   <ACORD>
    <SignonRq>
    <SignonPswd>
    <CustId>
    <CustLoginId>username</CustLoginId>
]]>
</tem:xmlData>
```

When I do the above, I also still get a 200 response, but I don't seem to get anything kicked back to me in the way of a response. I just get an empty response of:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <SubmitAndRateResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <SubmitAndRateResult/>
      </SubmitAndRateResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And I have no documentation or help to determine if my data is going in there correctly. Does my request look correct, and if so how can I test my data is going in there correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I did have similar issue recently, what i did is change all the  < and > signs to entity references (link to check them is below)

Check this out for more information:
[https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp#:~:text=Entity%20References,start%20of%20a%20new%20element.&text=Only%20%3C%20and%20%26%20are%20strictly%20illegal,%3E%20with%20%3E%20as%20well](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp#:%7E:text=Entity%20References,start%20of%20a%20new%20element.&text=Only%20%3C%20and%20%26%20are%20strictly%20illegal,%3E%20with%20%3E%20as%20well).